# How to convert HashMap<Object, int[]> values to a matrix

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to convert `HashMap<Object, int[]>` values to int[][].

I have HashMap of `<Character, int[]>` I want all the values of map in `int[][]`

```
merge(map.values().toArray());
```

this is throwing me a Compilation error.

```
Line 18: error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to int[][]
    int[][] arr = merge(map.values().toArray());
```

Signature of merge function.

```
public int[] merge(int[][] arr){   
//doing something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to convert `HashMap<Object, int[]>` values to `int[][]`.

I think the signature of your method is wrong, so to get an `int[][]` from values of map, you can use:

```
public static int[][] merge(Collection<int[]> arr){
    return arr.toArray(new int[0][]); // Java11+: return arr.toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

then you call merge method like this:

```
int[][] result = merge(map.values());
```